# How do remove space at top of web part zone?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, css

In my SharePoint Foundation site, I have a page with Text Layout set to "One column with sidebar". The left-hand column has a list web part, as does the right-hand column. However, the web part in the right-hand column is aligned to the top of the column, and the left-hand column has a space above the web part. I edit the HTML Source, and there is nothing above the div tag. How do I get rid of the space?

UPDATE: I found a solution when I upgraded to SharePoint 2013. It is listed below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I upgraded to SharePoint 2013, I saw the same issue occuring with a SINGLE Web Part Zone. My solution should probably work with SharePont 2010 as well. To reproduce the problem in SharePoint 2013:

- Create a page.
- Add a list to the page.
- Edit the web part and change the view.
- The list is displayed, but there is a small amount of space above the list.

To correct the problem:

- Click the "Format Text" tab.
- Click "Edit Source" from the ribbon.
- Select all HTML and copy to the clipboard. **NOTE:** There is a line return before the first  tag. Even if you remove it, it won't remove the space.
- Open SharePoint Designer (I haven't tried this with other editors, but it works within SharePoint Designer).
- Open a scratch (blank) .html page in SharePoint Designer.
- Paste from the clipboard. Notice the space is gone.
- Highlight the contents and copy to clipboard.
- Select the browser again and highlight the Edit Source text.
- Paste back on top of the highlighted text and click OK.
- Your list is now at the top of the page.

Comment: I found I could use Notepad instead of Designer. Not sure why the copying/paste into Notepad and then copy/paste into Edit Source fixes the problem, but it worked for me.

Comment: Because there are hidden characters in the Edit Source editor. That is the only explanation. Copying to Notepad ensures only the visible characters are copied to and from.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box both columns allow the Webpart to go to the top. It's very easy to get a web part in the left wrapped in a <h1>, but if you make sure to edit the HTML source of both columns so that they start with the <div class="ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox" contenteditable="false"> then they should align unless you have something in your theme/masterpage that offsets them.

If you look at the two columns in IE developer tools then the content of the divs with class ms-rte-layoutszone-inner should start the same way.

Comment: The HTML is identical.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue a couple weeks ago and had to add some css to my page to fix it. It seems that different ms-rtestate classes are applied to different Web Parts and end up with slight differences in the layout.

I doubt that my specific fix will work in your case, but here it is as a reference:

```
ms-rtestate-field table {
    border-collapse: separate!important;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Easiest:
Edit page, Click on the webpart, select the WEB PART tab, click "Minimize".