# Align app part in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to align the app part but without luck. When I add the app part it comes down, instead of being aligned with "Home".

Sharing the screenshot.[image: test app part].

When I inspect the elements in Chrome I can see `ms-rte-layoutszone-inner` have with `<span>&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;&#8203;</span>`.

See below:

[image: 2]]

Answer (score 0):

please try the following,

1. Edit the page --> click "Format Text" --> Edit Source --> remove unwanted "span" tag from the top of the page --> Click ok --> save the changes.

If the above dint work for you then please the steps mentioned in [How do remove space at top of web part zone](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32428/how-do-remove-space-at-top-of-web-part-zone)

Comment: steps in that link just work if you have just top heading but not if add the app part.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no extra line space above your app part when you add it.

If that doesn't work . . .

When I tried to add an app part(with an extra line space on top) I saw the spaces, but the html was a little different from yours. See below,
[image]

Once I set the 'display' to 'none' for the 'p' tag(in screenshot) it moved up and started to align with left nav. 
I had to set the margin for the body of the app part to '0px' to align it perfectly.

Comment: it helped but still i dont have aligned yet i think its because chrome title is there and when i do chrometitle to none from app part properties then its almost 1px down.